# In Unity, small text is choppy and not as clean as in Figma

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, textmeshpro

I have spent a lot of time trying to generate font in Unity with best results for small text. However, it is still choppy and nowhere near as clean as in Figma or other games that I have seen. Check the red arrow:
Compared to Figma, my text in unity (upper picture), is just a mess. How can I achieve AAA looking crispy small text in Unity ?
Next to the arrow, there are export settings for the font that I've used. I've spent couple of hours trying every setting. This is the best result I got in terms of clarity. Higher atlas resolution results in unreadable merged text below certain threshold of font size.
(upper picture Unity, below is a shot from Figma)[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://medium.com/@dan.liberatore/pixel-perfect-text-and-ui-in-unity-2021-56d60ba9370f

Comment: I find that turning of anti aliasing on the camera worked to get better and clearer text for me. Anti aliasing smoothens edges and makes the text blurry. Make a separate UI camera and render text on that one, then nothing else in the scene will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to make the Canvas small of such situation (Like really small 0.001 stuff) and making the font size very big like 200 or something. Then the text gets way clearer.

Answer (score 0):

use TextMeshPro with a high Antialiasing option or use a higher resolution in addition, or use post-processing Antialiasing
[image]

final word: Unity UI rendering can not be comparable with Figma quality because Unity uses a real-time rendering system and it is very different with none real-time software UI rendering